# Firebase firestore getting data from inside collection

Tags: swift, firebase

Is there a way to grab the data from owner ID I'm not able to access the collection oath because the `documentID` is auto-generated and not a specific value I have control of

[image: document screenshot]

Comment: Is a document dedicated to a single user? Then you should try replacing that document ID with user UID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible option would be to query your documents and retrieve a specifc OwnerID like this. 
If you want to fetch all OwnerIDs from all of your documents just remove the 'whereField'.

Also check out the Firebase documentation for [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

```
   let docRef = db.collection("YOURCOLLECTIONNAME")
   let query = docRef.whereField("OwnerID", isEqualTo:"VAL")

    query.getDocuments{ (querySnapshot, error) in
         if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
         }else {


              for documents in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {

                   if let owner = documents.get("OWnerID") as? String {
                      print(owner)
                    }
    }
```